# Difference between <filesystem> in libvirt domain xml and file based storage volumes

Tags: storage, libvirt

What are the differences between using filesystem tag in domain xml and using a file based storage volume ?

A directory on the host can be shared via the filesystem tag in domain xml and also as a storage pool via the 'dir' type. Is there any difference in these methods ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `<filesystem>`, it provides host file systems to guest OS, where you can open a directory, a single file, a given size of RAM or even block devices on host to a **LXC container**. Notice that when using Qemu/KVM, the only option is `type=mount`, which means you can get a mounted file system only. see the reference of [libvirt domain xml format](http://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#elementsFilesystems).

When using file based storage volume, it provides disks device to the virtual machine so that it can be detected as block storage. It's often used by Qemu/KVM and others.